# NestJS + Sentry - source maps not mapping correctly

Tags: node.js, nestjs, sentry, source-maps, tsc

I need to integrate NestJs-origin source maps into Sentry. I went through the official troubleshooting guide and nearly every issue on the Github Sentry repository but I still can't correctly connect the source maps so that Sentry would correctly display the original source code in the issue view. Here is the Sentry issue code section:

[image: Current Sentry view]

Here is also one of the stack frames (without any source map attached) in the event JSON payload:

```
{
  "function": "HealthCheckController.errorCheck1",
  "module": "health-check.controller.ts",
  "filename": "app:///dist/http-app/health-check.controller.ts",
  "abs_path": "app:///dist/http-app/health-check.controller.ts",
  "lineno": 16,
  "colno": 11,
  "in_app": true
}
```

Sentry SDK version: 7.54.0

Sentry CLI version: 2.18.1

For the build, I use `tsc` with the following config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2020",
    "sourceMap": true, // as suggested in official docs
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "inlineSources": true, // as suggested in official docs
    "sourceRoot": "/" // as suggested in official docs
  }
}
```

While searching for the solution, I also applied `RewriteFrames` Sentry integration to manually map the files to the correct source maps, here is the current config of it:

```
new RewriteFrames({
        iteratee: (frame) => {
          if (!frame.filename) return frame;
          const filename = path.basename(frame.filename);
          const fileDir = path.dirname(frame.filename);
          const relativePath = path
            .relative(process.cwd(), fileDir)
            .replace(/^src\//g, 'dist/');
          frame.filename = `app:///${relativePath}/${filename}`;
          return frame;
        },
})
```

In the CI pipeline, when the final image is built, the following code snippet is used to create a release, inject debug id and upload source maps to Sentry (`SENTRY_ORG`, `SENTRY_PROJECT`, `SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN` envs are correctly set):

```
sentry-cli releases new "$SENTRY_RELEASE"
sentry-cli releases set-commits --ignore-missing --auto "$SENTRY_RELEASE"
sentry-cli sourcemaps inject dist/
sentry-cli sourcemaps upload --release="$SENTRY_RELEASE" ./dist --url-prefix '~/dist' 
sentry-cli releases finalize "$SENTRY_RELEASE"
```

The source maps are uploaded and associated with the correct release (and if going deeper, I confirmed that issue is also connected to the correct release) and everything is visible in the dashboard.

[image: Uploaded js and js.map files]

Please, let me know what I'm doing wrong or some directions where the problem could be.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable auto mapping, to do this add a `--no-sourcemap-reference` in:

```
sentry-cli sourcemaps upload --release="$SENTRY_RELEASE" ./dist --url-prefix '~/dist' --no-sourcemap-reference
```